# Observing progress while using URLSessionDataTask and URLSessionDownloadTask both for same remote url

Tags: ios, uiprogressview, urlsession

I'm using `URLSessionDataTask` to show an image, and using `URLSessionDownloadTask` to download the image on my app. Also I needed to observe download progress, so I use KVO at `Progress`'s `fractionCompleted`.

The thing is `fractionCompleted` value just has **0.05** and **1.0**. I think this issue happened for using same remote url. Because when I don't use `URLSessionDataTask`(I can't show the image though), I get right progress update.

Why is it happened? Is there any reference?

#### Edited

First, I don't want to use `URLSession` delegate to get progress. I'm using two VCs(first one is `RemoteGridViewController` using `URLSessionDataTask` to show image and second one is `MediaViewerController`). `MediaViewerController` delegate to first VC for downloading the image **on camera roll**. I know I can use `URLSession` delegate method to notify progress by using `NotificationCenter` or something like that, but I don't want. This way makes strong coupling(?) between the VCs(I guess...)

Second, `RemoteGridViewControlle`r use `URLSession` to show an image by `URLSessionDataTask` and cache it.

```swift
guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
    completionHandler(.failure(NetworkManagerError.urlError))
    return
}

var req = URLRequest(url: url)
req.cachePolicy = .returnCacheDataElseLoad

if let cachedResponse = sharedCache?.cachedResponse(for: req) {
    completionHandler(.success(cachedResponse.data))
} else {
    sessionDataTask = session.dataTask(with: req) { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            completionHandler(.failure(error))
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, let data = data else {
            completionHandler(.failure(NetworkManagerError.dataError))
            return
        }
        self?.sharedCache?.storeCachedResponse(CachedURLResponse(response: response, data: data), for: req)
        completionHandler(.success(data))
    }
    
    sessionDataTask?.resume()
}
```

Third, `MediaViewerController` call `MediaViewerDelegate` method, which is `downloadImage(itemAt:for:)` to download an image.

```swift
extension RemoteGridViewController: MediaViewerDelegate {
    func downloadImage(itemAt indexPath: IndexPath, for mediaViewer: MediaViewerController) {
        let data = unsplashData[indexPath.item]
        let urlString = data.regular
        
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        
        mediaViewer.presentProgressView()

        networkManager.downloadTaskForImage(with: url, progressHandler: mediaViewer.observe(_:)) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let image):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    mediaViewer.toastView(with: true)
                }
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
            case .failure(let error):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    mediaViewer.toastView(with: false)
                }
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}

class NetworkManager {
    private let session: URLSession!
    private var sessionDownloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask?
    
    func downloadTaskForImage(with url: URL, progressHandler: (Progress?) -> (), completionHandler: @escaping (Result<UIImage, Error>) -> ()) {
        sessionDownloadTask = session.downloadTask(with: url) { (location, response, error) in
            if let error = error {
                completionHandler(.failure(error))
                return
            }
            
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) else {
                completionHandler(.failure(NetworkManagerError.responseError))
                return
            }
            
            guard let location = location else {
                completionHandler(.failure(NetworkManagerError.urlError))
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: location)
                if let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                    completionHandler(.success(image))
                } else {
                    completionHandler(.failure(NetworkManagerError.dataError))
                }
            } catch let error {
                completionHandler(.failure(error))
            }
        }
        
        progressHandler(sessionDownloadTask?.progress)
        sessionDownloadTask?.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rob Oh, my mistake. I edited the post.

Comment: Still more clarity is needed to understand your question. At what place you need to measure the progress of downloading the image?

Comment: @NirmitDagly MediaViewerController present progressView, so this progressView need to measure the progress. That's why I use `mediaViewer.observe(_:)` on `downloadTaskForImage(with:progressHandler:completionHandler:)`. To be clear, feel free to ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can track for the downloaded bytes to total expected bytes to track the progress of downloading image.

Use following delegate method:

```
URLSession(_:downloadTask:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:)
```

and following snippet:

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
        // println("download task did write data")

        let progress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
        
        //Your code to download and save image to camera role
    }
}
```

I hope this may have resolved your query to check for exact progress with downloading.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but **I said** I don't want to use `URLSession delegate`. I used it before actually, but I thought there is no way to notify progress to `DownloadAlertController` other than `NotificationCenter`, and using `NotificationCenter` doesn't fit what I was going for. Can you explain how you intended to notify that progress to other VC?